# $\sigma$-algebra Generated by a Random Variable contains all of its null sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How does one show that $\sigma(X) \equiv \{\{X \in A\}: A\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ contains all of its null sets?

Let $N$ be such a null set for this $\sigma$-algebra. We know $\exists A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $N \subseteq \{X \in A\}$ and $P(X \in A) = 0$

If $N \in \sigma(X)$, then $$N \subseteq \{X \in \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}): N \subseteq \{X \in A\}} A \equiv A_N \}$$

with $P(X \in A_N) = 0$.  How does one show equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

It is not in general true that $\sigma(X)$ contains all of its null sets.

E.g. start with probability space $([0,1],\mathcal A,m)$ where $\mathcal A$ is the collection of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ and $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure restricted to $\mathcal A$.

Let random variable $X:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $x\mapsto x$.

Then $\sigma(X)$ is the collection of Borel subsets of $[0,1]$.

This collection does not contain all its null sets.